# Как у свойства объекта сделать проверку допустимых значений?

Tags: javascript

Например user.age - от 18 лет.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Классический пример для сеттеров объекта.
Попробуй их использовать.

Они позволяют делать проверку прямо при присванивании свойства через

```
user.age = 99;
```

Подробнее
[https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters#да-здравствуют-get-set](https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters#%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-get-set)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

можно так:

```
var minAge = 18;

if(user.age >= minAge){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, речь о том, чтобы объекту даже присвоить недопустимое значение нельзя было.